# import "anychart" typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, anychart

I tried to import "anychart" in my .ts file like this:

```
import 'anychart';
```

When I add this line all of my HTML page in my localhost serve is deleted.

**My .ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetDataService } from '../../services/get-data.service';
import 'anychart';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-venn',
  templateUrl: './venn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venn.component.css']
})
export class VennComponent implements OnInit {

  //chart: anychart.charts.Venn;
  pizza3Field = [];

  constructor(
    private getDataService: GetDataService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.pizza3Field = data;
    })
  }
}
```

**My HTML file:**

```
<p>venn works!</p>
```

Anyone have this or a similar problem?

Answer (score -2):

The [demo sample](https://github.com/anychart-integrations/anychart-angular5/) describes how to use AnyChart in Angular.